# Unable to access AWS Key boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I am trying to transfer some files from s3 to Google Cloud storage. I have my connection to AWS set up as:

```
s3 = boto3.resource(
    service_name='s3',
    region_name='us-west-2',
    aws_access_key_id='TEST',
    aws_secret_access_key='TEST'
)
```

I can then print buckets successfully using:

```
# Print out bucket names
for bucket in s3.buckets.all():
    print(bucket.name)
```

I have a function to chunk the data:

```
def read_in_chunks(file_object, chunk_size=1024):
    while True:
        data = file_object.read(chunk_size)
        if not data:
              break
        yield data

CHUNK_SIZE = 256 * 1024 * 1024 # 256MB
PART_SIZE = 256 * 1024 * 1024  # 256MB
```

I set the source/destination

```
destination_gcs_url = 'gs://tmp/test-004.record'
source_s3_url ='s3://data/record/20201130_1841/test-004.record'


chunk_index = 0
print('Starting the sink')

with open(destination_gcp_url, 'wb', transport_params={'min_part_size' :PART_SIZE}) as gcp_sink:
    with open(source_s3_url, 'rb', transport_params={'session': session}, ignore_ext=True) as s3_source:
        for piece in read_in_chunks(s3_source, CHUNK_SIZE):
            print('Read: ' + size(chunk_index * CHUNK_SIZE) + " ("+ str(chunk_index) + ")")
            gcp_sink.write(piece)
         
        chunk_index = chunk_index + 1

print('done')
```

I then get the error:

```
OSError: unable to access bucket: 'data' key: '/record/20201130_1841/test-004.record' version: None error: An error occurred (InvalidAccessKeyId) when calling the GetObject operation: The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records.
```

Comment: Can you try creating the S3 object inside the function itself. Because clearly the error says that the credentials are invalid but considering that you are able to print the buckets using the same creds, it's clearly unable to read them.

Comment: It's still giving me the same error.

Comment: Which line is generating the error? It would appear that you are using [smart-open](https://pypi.org/project/smart-open/), is that correct? Please edit your question to show where `session` is defined.